# BI Publisher - RTF Matrix Template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have a data model like this:

```
<LIST_MONTH>
    <MONTH>
        <MONTH_NUM>01</MONTH_NUM><MONTH_NAME>JAN</MONTH_NAME>
            <LIST_TITLE>
                <TITLE>
                    <TITLE_NAME>Title 1</TITLE_NAME>
                    <LIST_SCORE>
                        <SCORE>
                            <SCORE1>8.0</SCORE1><SCORE2>5.0</SCORE2><SCORE3>7.0</SCORE3>
                        </SCORE>
                    </LIST_SCORE>
                </TITLE>
                <TITLE>
                    <TITLE_NAME>Title 2</TITLE_NAME>
                    <LIST_SCORE>
                        <SCORE>
                            <SCORE1>7.0</SCORE1><SCORE2>9.0</SCORE2><SCORE3>8.0</SCORE3>
                        </SCORE>
                    </LIST_SCORE>
                </TITLE>            
            </LIST_TITLE>
    </MONTH>
    <!--FEB's data is here-->
</LIST_MONTH>
```

**Which is the solution for displaying data like this:**

```
                Title 1                 Title 2                 Title 3

JAN                8.0                     7.0
                   5.0                     9.0
                   7.0                     8.0

FEB                6.0                     8.0                     5.0 
                   9.0                     7.0                     9.0
                   5.0                     7.0                     7.0
```

I've used privot table but it did not work and I felt that privot table is too much difficult to custom.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is already pivoted, I think it would be to much work representing this on the report. If you could 'unpivot' the data and get the XML to [look like in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_rtf_tmpl.htm#BIPRD2542), you might get somewhere letting BIP do the pivoting.

I guess you could also work with all kinda small subgroups and tables within tables to get to your result though.. use the @column and @row for the months and titles first in a 2x2 table, then in the 4th cell create a new group etc. Goodluck